# React.js user conversation UI design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am planning on designing a new discussion UI in React where users should be able to post a comment and reply to a specific comment.

I use a NoSQL key-value based DB - DynamoDB. However, I am not sure how to design the database so that I can render the sub comments in React. In other words how to bind a comment to a sub comment and enable users to reply to each other?

So far i have decided that i will register to the DB the following:

```
try {
      const id = "randomUUID";

      await addComment({ id, username, comment });
    } catch {
      alert(`something went wrong!!!`);
    }
```

also a sandbox link to a short draft of my ideas:

https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-lamarr-3iv0c?file=/src/Discussion.js

Comment: Consider renaming your post title to something like "Modeling Comment Threads in DynamoDB".  Your title makes it look like you have a UI/React question when it's really a question about data modeling in DynamoDB.

Answer (score 1):

The DynamoDB documentation has an [example Forum application](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SampleData.CreateTables.html#SampleData.CreateTables2).  The example has table definitions, sample data and instructions on how to replicate the application in your own environment.  Among other things, it models Forums, Threads and Replies.

You may want to take a look at how they've designed their application and see if it applies to your access patterns.